# How do I find out if generic is instanceof a class in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following classes/sub-classes defined.

```
public class Vehicle
{
}

public class Car extends Vehicle
{
}

public class Aircraft extends Vehicle
{
}
```

Now, I'm trying to loop through a list of vehicle records where the list can contain cars and aircraft.  But, I'd like to figure out if it's an aircraft record (and not a car record).  The compiler is telling me "error: illegal generic type for instanceof if(s instanceof Record<Aircraft>)" on the instance of check.  What am I missing?  Forgive me, I haven't used java in years.

```
        for (Record<? extends Vehicle> s : rs.getResultReadOnly())
        {                    
            if(s instanceof Record<Aircraft>) 
            {
               ...
            }                    
        }
```

Comment: Record<Aircraft> is the definition of the List, the actual type is the type of the class which is Aircraft as @Nambari said

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this type of check because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html): The generic information `<Aircraft>` will be lost at runtime.

However you can do something like this:

```
if (s.getVehicle() instanceof Aircraft) { 
  ..
}
```