# Checking if Generic Class is instanceof Abstract Class

Tags: java, class, abstract, instanceof

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Class b = B.class;
    System.out.println(b.isAssignableFrom(A.class));
}
static abstract class A{

}
static class B extends A{

}
```

Output:

```
false
```

The output is false I try to use instanceof and it has compile errors please help

Edit is solved you need to compare baseclass is assignable from extended pretty stupid that you can't use is class instanceof abstract anyways

Comment: There are no generics here.  And the result is correct, you cannot assign to a `B` from an `A`.

Comment: Please **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-), which states: *"Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a **superclass** or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter"*. Since `B` is not a super of `A`, method returns `false`. --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: If you wanted the equivalent of `b instanceof A`, then reverse the call: `A.class.isAssignableFrom(b)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out if generic is instanceof a class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642586/how-do-i-find-out-if-generic-is-instanceof-a-class-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Your class `B` extends from `A`, not the other way around. Imagine a more concrete example like

```
public abstract class Animal { ... }
public class Dog extends Animal { ... }
public class Cat extends Animal { ... }
```

The result of `B.class.isAssignableFrom(A.class)` is correctly `false` since you are asking

> Can I assign an `Animal` (`A`) to a `Dog` (`B`)?

Which is not possible in general since there can be different animals like the `Cat`.

```
Animal animal = new Cat();
Dog dog = (Dog) animal; // Will not work since animal is a cat
```

For more details see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-) of the method:

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either **the same as**, or is a **superclass** or **superinterface** of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It returns `true` if so; otherwise it returns `false`. If this Class object represents a **primitive type**, this method returns `true` if the specified Class parameter is exactly this Class object; otherwise it returns `false`.
>
> Specifically, this method **tests** whether the type represented by the specified Class parameter can be **converted to** the type represented by this Class object via an **identity conversion** or via a **widening reference conversion**. See The Java Language Specification, sections [5.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.1) and [5.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.4), for details.

Comment: "Can I assign an Animal (A) to a Dog (B)?" Well since B extends A it should be returning true I think java is wrong here. Because dog is an animal and it can be casted back to an animal. For example if they were both objects I could say is dog instanceof animal and it would return true then I say is dog assignable to animal says false. Java is definitely wrong there. Now if you said cat is assignable to dog then it should return false but, not if it extends it

Comment: Yeah I just noticed it says from. They should have class.isInstanceof() or fix the compiler to allow for if(classObject instanceof AbtractClass) {
//do code
}

Comment: The logic is reversed to what you think. The method asks the question the other way around. It asks if an animal can be assigned to a dog. Or, equivalently if a dog is assignable **from** an animal.

Comment: Well, there is [Class#isInstance(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-). It returns the same as the `instanceof` operator. So you can do `Animal.class.isInstance(dog)` and also try `Dog.class.isInstance(animal)` which would return `true` if the animal is of type `Dog`, like you could do `if (dog instanceof Animal)` or `if (animal instanceof Dog)`.